# Verify method was not invoked on a certain thread

Tags: java, multithreading, mocking, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a class which is used by the SUT. I want to check that a certain method on that mocked class was not invoked on a certain thread (main).

- How would I do that?
- Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```
public class ToBeMocked {
    public invokeMeInBackground() {

        // do stuff
    }
}

public class SUT {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toBeMocked.invokeMeInBackground();
        }
    }).start();

}
```

- How can I make sure that SUT calls invokeMeInBackground() on a non-main-thread?
- Is this possible with other mocking frameworks?

I know I can check that it was invoked and for how many times with verify()

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the solution you were looking for, but I would use Dependency Injection.  I'd introduce a new "middle-man" class, BackgroundRunner, just to make the testing easier:

```
public interface InvokableInBackground {
    public void invokeMeInBackground();
}

public class ToBeMocked implements InvokableInBackground {
    public void invokeMeInBackground() {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class BackgroundRunner {
    public void invokeInBackground(InvokableInBackground invokableInBackground) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invokableInBackground.invokeMeInBackground();
        }
    }).start();
    }
}

public class SUT {
      final BackgroundRunner backgroundRunner;
      final ToBeMocked toBeMocked;

      SUT(BackgroundRunner backgroundRunner, ToBeMocked toBeMocked) {
          this.backgroundRunner = backgroundRunner;
          this.toBeMocked = toBeMocked;
      }

      void methodToBeTested(...) {
          ToBeMocked toBeMocked = ...;
          backgroundRunner.invokeInBackground(toBeMocked);
      }
}
```

Your unit test would then provide two test doubles, one for the ToBeMocked object, and one for the BackgroundRunner object.  It could then verify that the BackgroundRunner object's invokeInBackground() method was called with toBeMocked as its argument.

In the shop where I work, everyone would agree that the BackgroundRunner class (whose *complete* implementation, you see above) is sufficiently simple that *it* does not need testing.

---

Afterthought:  That BackgroundRunner class that I've just invented looks an awful lot like a simplistic version of an ExecutorService.

Comment: It does look like a simplistic `ExecutorService`—in fact, you could have BackgroundRunner [implement `Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), which is an interface that simply defines `execute(Runnable)`.